# How Textstream Read/Write methods work in VB 6?

Tags: java, file, vb6, refactoring

VB application is re-engineered to java.
There is a ZIP file which is read using TextStream.Read(file.size) method in the VB application and this is stored in the DB(coloumn having IMAGE as its data type in Sql).
How can we read this from java and write to a file so that the ZIP file is valid.
Is there any particular way of writing/handling these files in java ?

I have found that Textstream.Read method returns a string, but then what is the encoding thats used here and should some characters be removed from the string like newline characters ?

Just to add i am using hibernate , mapped as binary type to retrieve this coloumn.

Comment: Are you sure VB6 is involved at all here?  All I see is what looks like VB.Net objects such as TextStream.

Comment: @BobRiemersma "Textstream" is part of the "Scripting Runtime" or the "FileSystemObject" collection for VB6, they may have improved it for .Net but it was available in VB6.

Comment: Yes that's true of course.  I suppose the idea of reading a ZIP file using the FSO threw me since it cannot handle binary data.  Thanks for correcting me on this.

Comment: Perhaps this is something to do with ADODB stream seeing a db is mentioned (http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_stream.asp) ?

Comment: @all i have noticied the difference in file size when i retreived this coloumn(inserted in VB).Reason i found is, many spaces were introduced i.e in between characters when compared to the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

TextStream encoding is documented in the help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59(v=vs.85).aspx

Default is "ANSI" (using current PC code page) if the encoding is not specified